# Modal isn't staying in a fixed position - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

For some reason, my Twitter Bootstrap modals don't seem to be working correctly. On a long page, the modal doesn't stay fixed on the screen - and is instead displayed at the top of the page.

The modals are displaying at the top instead of staying on-screen and fixed.

I hope this makes sense, and someone might know what's going wrong here. Something in the wrong place, something missing possibly?

Comment: for me, modal is not fixed or stick on top..as if i will scroll down then it won't stick to top..you want it in center with fixed position?

Comment: could you put your code in a fiddle please? When you will resolve the issue, the question code will dissapear..

Comment: @clement doing so right now, hold on a minute! (never used jsfiddle before so I'm trying to figure it out)

Comment: @leo yes I'm looking for it to be centered and fixed, right now when you scroll down it stays at the top for some odd reason, even though it's set to fixed.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-fixed-position.php - waiting for jsfiddle :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probleme should be only in webkit browsers, cause in core.css you have added

```
body {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

If you remove this, everything should be fine.

Comment: Welp, that worked, thank you so much! I actually had that in there during April 1st when we were rotating the web page as a little joke. That explains it, again - thanks!